# Microsoft WCF Test Client: How to specify client certificate?

Tags: c#, wcf

This is my first time with WCF so please bear with me. I'm trying to consume a service which requires client certificate authentication. I've that installed on my machine. I'm using Microsoft WCF Test client to play around with this service.

I'm just not sure where to specify this certificate in the proxy request?

I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

This is the screenshot of the function I'm trying to invoke on the service (where should I add the cert thumbprint?):

[image: Function]

Appreciate any help.

Edit: Is this the right way? Not sure what will go in "ClaimType".. ClaimValue = My cert thumbprint, correct?

[image: Cert]

Comment: Not sure exactly what am I looking at in the screenshots. In the left hand pane of the WCF Test Client where you can find the list of services and operations, you can also find a config file. You can right click on that file and edit it. You'll need to add the certificate details in the config file under the security tag of the appropriate binding.